# How to labelencode multiple columns for train and test set separately

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am building a Random Forest model and there are 3 categorical variable in my training dataset. sklearn RandomForest wont allow categorical variables in the model

I used Labelencoder() to convert these variable to numerical variable using fit_transform on train set and but I am getting error while running the transform on test set

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
le = LabelEncoder()
X_train.apply(le.fit_transform)

X_test.apply(le.transform)
```

I am getting the below error message:

ValueError: ("y contains new labels: ['female' 'male']", 'occurred at index Sex')

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] so someone can figure out how to reproduce your problem and determine a fix.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you have a typo in your `Sex` column, one of the values is seems to be `['female' 'male']` instead of something along the lines of `['female', 'male']` (notice in the former, the two values are not separated by a comma, and are therefore not read as separate elements). Make sure you fix that typo before you apply `train_test_split` or split your data however you are doing it. For instance, you could look at `df.Sex.unique()` (where `df` is your dataset), and make sure that you only have your expected values `['male', 'female']`

The underlying error is that `LabelEncoder` is finding a value in your `X_test` that is not found in your `X_train`, so it doesn't know how to transform it (since you only fit `LabelEncoder` on the values found in `X_train`). This will only potentially happen if you have very rare values in your dataset (in which case, you might want to reconsider your data, or reprocess it in an appropriate way), but *if* you want to avoid this completely, one viable option would be to fit `LabelEncoder` *before* you split the data into `train` and `test`